# Opening page in the background of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am making a website that has two div columns. within the right column I have a number of buttons which when I click on I would like them to open behind the buttons on the right column so you can still see the buttons. I would ideally like to do this without the use of Iframes. I have tried using Ajax, but am not sure why it doesn't work. Here's the code:

css:

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
}

#main,
#col_l,
#col_r
{
height: 100%;
}

div[id*="col"]
{
float: left;
width: 50%;
overflow: auto;
}   

#col_r{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("col_r").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("POST","video.html",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

HTML Link:

```
<div id=col_r>
<a href="javascript: loadXMLDoc();">test</a>
</div>
```

Let me know your thoughts. Thanks alot!

Comment: Why don't you want to use iframes?

Comment: Hi RononDex, I am trying to create a site where the right column links  perform a "ScrollTo" to the content in the left column via the ID of each section on the left. I haven't been able to figure out how to implement this with frames so that one communicates to another. from what I understand doing this in divs is easier unless you have any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at the following jquery plugin that allows you to send data from and to iframes: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be two possible problems:

1. You need run your html from a local http server (something like `localhost:3000/index.html`);  Your code won't run correctly if you open it directly from the file system, such as `file:///D:/index.html` in the url bar. It's will return the following error in console:

   **XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/video.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.**
2. Try use `xmlhttp.open("GET","video.html",true);` instead of `POST` method if you simply read static html files.

Comment: Hi Ruocaled, thanks a lot for your reply. The problem was that it wasn't running on a local server! The video now opens but not in the right div ("col_r"). Also text and links on the right div seem to disappear once the video opens. Any ideas why? Would appreciate your thoughts

Comment: @Houmy your code `.innerHTML=` replaces the content of `col_r` div with whatever inside `video.html`. No idea why it doesn't show in the right div, works fine for me. Could open up a new question with more details.